# How remove the Space from the bottom of the output?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to get the following output?

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

Here is my code in python

```
n = int(input(" Please Enter any Number: "))

j=1
while j<=n:
    print('*'* j)
    j+=1

while n>=1:
    print('*'* (n-1))
    n=n-1
    #print(n)
```

but the problem is it gives me the following output

```
*
**
***
**
*

basically I am getting an extra space after the output.
```

Does anyone know what is the reason behind this and what is the remedy for the same.

Comment: Next time, if you decide to golf. Try this out `'\n'.join('*'*int(i) for i in str(pow(int('1'*n),2)))` (Works till n=9)

Answer (score 5):

You need

```
while n>=2:
```

in the last loop. Otherwise a further line with zero (1-1=0) stars is plotted at the end

Comment: I am so fool, I didn't see that, thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

Why not rewrite your `while` loops with `for` loops which is as I think more appropriate for that task with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#range)?

```
n = 5
for i in range(1, n):
    print('*' * i)
for j in range(n, 0, -1):
    print('*' * j)
```

Resulted to:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
****
***
**
*
```

**EDIT**

Or you could even write it with one liner with two `list comprehension` and str `join` method:

```
n = 3
print('\n'.join(['*' * i for i in range(1, n)] + ['*' * j for j in range(n, 0, -1)]))

*   
**  
*** 
**  
*
```